# Can you insert/update/delete rows in LinqPad via a grid?

Tags: linqpad

Perhaps this is beyond the purpose of LinqPad, but does it have this functionality that is available in SQL Management Studio?

I want to seutp some quick data but don't want to have to write code to do it.  I just want to type it in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, provided your tables have primary keys set.

All you have to do is put your results to data grids (Ctrl+Shift+G) then query the table you want to add rows to.  If you're just adding rows and don't need to see existing rows, you can filter it out (`YourTable.Take(0)`).  The key is to make sure that the query type is `IQueryable<YourTable>`.

[image: empty query]

You will be presented with a grid of the results of the query.  There should be a button up top to `Edit Data`.  There should be an empty row at the end (or you could click on `Add Row`) where you can enter your data.

Comment: Only in Developer/Premium licenses